# Descobrindo o valor binário no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary

Existe alguma função no SQL Server que converta um número inteiro em binário ?
Exemplo:

```
SELECT Funcao_Binario(2) -> Saida : 0010
SELECT Funcao_Binario(4) -> Saída : 0100
SELECT Funcao_Binario(5) -> Saída : 0101
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função para isto:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DecimalToBinary]
(
    @Input bigint
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Output varchar(255) = ''

    WHILE @Input > 0 BEGIN

        SET @Output = @Output + CAST((@Input % 2) AS varchar)
        SET @Input = @Input / 2

    END

    RETURN REVERSE(@Output)

END
```

E usar desta forma:

```
SELECT dbo.DecimalToBinary(2);
SELECT dbo.DecimalToBinary(4);
SELECT dbo.DecimalToBinary(5);
```

Fonte:

> http://improve.dk/converting-between-base-2-10-and-16-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando operações bitwise:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Int2Binary (@i INT) RETURNS NVARCHAR(16) AS BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i & 32768 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i & 16384 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  8192 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  4096 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  2048 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  1024 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &   512 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &   256 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &   128 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    64 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    32 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    16 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     8 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     4 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     2 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     1 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END
END;
GO
```

Uso:

```
SELECT dbo.Int2Binary(2)
SELECT dbo.Int2Binary(50)
```

O maior inteiro passível de conversão é 65536, já que está sendo utilizado varchar(16) na função acima.

Fonte: http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/169/T-SQL-Converting-between-Decimal-Binary-and-Hexadecimal.aspx